# C++ Network Programming and Sockets

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to learn network programming and threads for C++. In order to learn the basics, I've decided to create a very simple project that consists of a server and a client, where I should be able to start multiple clients and all of them should be able to send and receive data from the server. The problem however is that I've been searching and searching but all I find is either Unix-specific or something that seems way to advanced for the basics that I want to learn.

I've already figured out that I can start a new thread in C++ by this simple line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>

void func1()
{
    printf("This is function 1!\n");
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1 (func1);   // Starts a new thread that runs func1.
    return 0;
}
```

While I understand that network programming is most likely not this strightforward it still seems like I find examples that are way to complicated. For instance, some of the examples that I've found (for Windows) requires both special libraries and loads of initialization.

However, it feels like that if I can create a new thread with just 1 line it should atleast be possible to create a new socket and connect it in a fairly strightforward way.

To make it easier for you to understand what I actually mean/want, I'll give an example below (this is not real code, just an example):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <socket>

int main()
{
    Socket s = (...);   // Required initialization.
    s = connect(...);   // Connect the socket to the server.

    // Now we have a connected socket and can
    // send/receive information with the server.
}
```

So my questions are therefore:

- Is there really no simple way of creating a new socket in C++ that is not platform specific and that requires separate libraries etc?
- If there is, could I please get some help/tips to get started?
- If there's not, where's a good place to learn the absolute basics?

Comment: Sockets are pretty much inherently platform specific unless abstracted by a library. Why would such a thing be supported at the language level? - C++ applications can be written for devices that have no concept of network connectivity. Please do not be afraid to use libraries! They simplify programming and allow you to benefit from other people's work "stand on the shoulders of giants". Furthermore asking for links to tutorials is not appropriate on StackOverflow.

Comment: `#include <socket>`?!? Sure? No, there's no simple way like this. Check for `boost::asio` et. al.

Comment: C++ will have a tentatively-standardized facility for sockets [soon](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4243.html). It's based on the aforementioned [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) library.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Ok, I understand. I'm not affraid of libraries, it's just that it quickly becomes so messy code when using different libraries for everything. And while network-programming is a such common task these days (its used for pretty much all larger applications), I thought that there should be some simple way to implement it. For instance, threads are probably platform specific too (I think) but still aviable in a such easy way. Oh, and I was not asking for links so much as just some hints in the right direction.

Comment: As others have mentioned `boost` is a fairly good starting point... Sometimes boost libraries can be a bit obtuse, but they're usually well written, tested extensively, and can become standardized because they are so widely used.

Comment: If your real intention is to learn, you should first understand what sockets are, understand the system-calls involved in network programming. Wrapper classes wouldn't help you learn and understand!